# Updating a column based on another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssms, etl

I have a stored procedure that takes values from an ADF pipeline to write watermark values in a SQL Server table. The new watermark value essentially replaces the old one, leaving no record for the old one.

However, my new requirement is to keep the old watermark value as well.

My current proc that helps update the table is simple.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_write_watermark] @LastModifiedtime datetime, @TableName varchar(50)
AS

BEGIN

UPDATE watermarktable
SET [WatermarkValue] = @LastModifiedtime
WHERE [TableName] = @TableName

END
```

the output im after is like this:

| Table | OldWaterMark | NewWaterMark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TableA | 22/12/2022 | 23/12/2022 |
| TableB | 21/12/2022 | 22/12/2022 |

and so forth. I don't want a growing list, but want NewWaterMark to replace the old watermark when the New one is modified. I hope I am making sense.

Please ask questions if I haven't explained well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by just adding one more line to your UPDATE statement. This extra line saves the current watermark into the old watermark field.

```
UPDATE watermarktable
SET [OldWaterMark] = [NewWatermark],
    [NewWatermark] = @LastModifiedtime  
WHERE [TableName] = @TableName
```

Note that when you're putting in the first watermark for a table (so that up until then, the `newwatermark` is NULL), this NULL value is transferred to `oldwatermark`. Only the second update - where `newwatermark` already has a value - is a non-NULL value copied to `oldwatermark`.